# Buildbot running sequential builders after they're finished

Tags: buildbot

Are there any triggers or anyway to set up buildbot to run builds after another have finished?  Right now I have multiple builders set up to turn on a machine, build, and turn off a machine.  I've set it up in a nightly schedule where it turns on the machine then 15 minutes after it would run a build then shuts off the machine about an hour after it started building.

I'd rather have 1 builder that does all 3 steps automatically.  Run builder1, waits X minutes, run builder2, waits Y minutes, run builder3.

Answer (score 1):

I think you either want to make the machine into a [Latent Slave](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-buildslaves.html#latent-buildslaves) so that you don't need separate builders.

Or you can use [Triggering schedulers](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#step-Trigger) to trigger from one builder to the next.